# How can I set an objects value before I have the object? Redux initial state question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, javascript-objects

I have this object:

```
   export const INITIAL_STATE = {
      inputs: {},
      isFetching: false,
    };
```

I need to update the `inputs` value from `{}` to:

```
{ 
  tableOne: {},
  tableTwo: {},
}
```

How can I do that? Because I don't know the key to the object until later. I was thinking this would work if the key was always 0. But, the key isn't always 0 and it's random:

```
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  inputs: { 
    0: defaultInput
  },
  isFetching: false,
};
```

Comment: when exactly is "later"? But if you mean some time after your app initialises, can't you just have the initialState with empty `inputs`, as in your first snippet, then update it via a reducer at that "later" time when you have this information?

Comment: Yea, I can do that - but then I have a lot of duplicate code. That duplicate code is the {tableOne: {}, tableTwo: {},} object. And so I figured that I could move that into the `INITIAL_STATE` variable, but I don't initially have the keys to the object.

Comment: I don't see why this would lead to duplicate code - but I obviously don't understand exactly what you're doing. If your question is really "how do I remove this duplicate code" then perhaps ask that, as a separate question, giving examples of the duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but it seems that the easiest way here would be to have an action with payload shaped `{ key: "tableX", value: "whatever" }`.

In pseudocode, it could look like this:

```
// actions.js

const createInput = (payload) => ({ type: "CREATE_INPUT", payload });

// example action:
dispatch(createInput({ key: "tableOne", value: {} });

// reducer.js

switch (action) {
  case "CREATE_INPUT":
    return {
      ...state,
      inputs: {
        ...state.inputs,
        [payload.key]: payload.value,
      }
    },
}
```